# Erlang record handling using filter

Tags: erlang, record

I have the following code to return a record from a list of records that has a field with value equal to Accountnumber.

```
lookup(AccountNumber, [#account{no=AccountNumber} = Rec | _]) ->
    Rec;
lookup(AccountNumber, [_| T]) ->
    lookup(AccountNumber, T);
lookup(AccountNumber, []) ->
    not_found.
```

The above code works fine, but when I try to convert it to filter using the following code:

```
lookup(AccountNumber, DBRef) ->
    lists:filter(fun(#account{no=AccountNumber} = Rec) -> Rec end, DBRef).
```

I got the following error:

```
** exception error: no case clause matching #account{no = 2,balance = 0,pin = undefined,name = "Ali",
                                                 transactions = []}
   in function  lists:'-filter/2-lc$^0/1-0-'/2 (lists.erl, line 1271)
```

What is the reason for the error?

Comment: Though it may be tempting to rewrite a recursive function like the one above using well-known functions like map, fold and filter, remember that `filter` will find *all* matching elements, meaning it always searches the entire list. (That also means that it can return multiple hits, not just the first one!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple problems in the code

1.The filter should always return atom true or false for all list elements. This is causing you the error.

2.When the variable outside the fun block is used in fun header, they are not patterned matched, the variable outside is masked. Hence the pattern match fails.

You can see the modified code below.

```
  lookup(AccountNumber, DBRef)  ->
    lists:filter(
      fun(#account{no=AccNo}) when AccNo =:= AccountNumber -> true;
         (_) -> false 
      end, DBRef).
```

Comment: In order to behave like the `lookup` function above you need to case on the result of `filter` to see if it returns the empty list (`not_found`) or a the list `[Req]`. Right now it returns `[Req]` on success and `[]` on failure. You'll also need to take into account the possibility that multiple accounts with the same number exist.